# WP8 Facebook Connect Crashes

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've attempted to look for a solution to my issue but unfortunately no avail :(

I initially wrote the code myself off an example I found online (transcribed) but I continually got an error when using the connection. It works all the way through login, installing the app to the Facebook account but the final bit (redirection with the key) it fails. Here is the error: (not enough rep to post in here)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Wf2.png

I thought at first maybe I had made an error in my code but this isn't the case either... As I downloaded the sample code ( [[FOUND HERE]](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Integrate_Facebook_to_Your_Windows_Phone_Application) ) and I get the same issue when compiling and logging into Facebook.

Now I know the app is successfully installing to the user account on Facebook because after I have finished the process (even on the error) I can manage my apps in Facebook and there it is all using my personal info and all.

I have no idea how to get past this... Oh great internet gurus, what's my next move?

Comment: The example you reference doesn't use the [Facebook .NET SDK](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/), I'd give that a go first as it supports all the API features. It's available on NuGet too.

Comment: That worked a treat Neil... thank you very much!

Comment: Great! You can accept your own answer btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the amazing suggestion by [Neil Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247257/neil-turner) this has been resolved.

Simply need to use the Facebook .NET SDK as suggested by his comment above.